# Facing issues with typescript multi hierarchy key map pair

Tags: javascript, typescript, maps, hierarchy

How do I change this structure so that I can get the values of this object like a map
this is my const object

```
const dependencyMetrics : {[dependancyName : string] :  {[name : string] : MetricInfo }[]} = {
    MyService : [{
        failure : {
            metric: new Metric({
                namespace: 'namespace',
                metricName: 'ABC'
            }),
            metricProperties: {
                period: Duration.seconds(60),
                statistic: 'Average'
            }
        },
        time : {
            metric: new Metric({
                namespace: 'namespace',
                metricName: 'age'
            }),
            metricProperties: {
                period: Duration.seconds(60),
                statistic: 'Average'
            }
        }
    }]};
//I am using this  also as a type : 
type MetricInfo = {
    metric  : Metric;
    metricProperties : MetricOptions;
}
```

What I want is this code to behave smoothly when I try some thing like : dependencyMetric.MyService.failure
or dependencyMetric.MyService.time

currently getting a lot of Objects and stuff don't know how to make this a hierarchy map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current structure treats `MyService` as a key for an array of objects. Which is why your getting unexpected results when trying to access `failure` or `time`

From what i understood, you want `MyService` to be a key for an object containing `failure` and `time` metrics, not an array.

Try this:

```
const dependencyMetrics : {[dependencyName : string] :  {[name : string] : MetricInfo }} = {
    MyService : {
        failure : {
            metric: new Metric({
                namespace: 'namespace',
                metricName: 'ABC'
            }),
            metricProperties: {
                period: Duration.seconds(60),
                statistic: 'Average'
            }
        },
        time : {
            metric: new Metric({
                namespace: 'namespace',
                metricName: 'age'
            }),
            metricProperties: {
                period: Duration.seconds(60),
                statistic: 'Average'
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Your `MetricInfo` type will stay the same

**Edit:**

First, to add more services to your `dependencyMetrics` object, you can just include them in the object:

```
const dependencyMetrics : {[dependencyName : string] :  {[name : string] : MetricInfo }} = {
    MyService1 : {
        // ...metrics for MyService1
    },
    MyService2 : {
        // ...metrics for MyService2
    },
    // add as many services as you need
};
```

Then, to access the metrics of a specific service dynamically, you can use the bracket notation to get the value associated with a key:

```
let serviceName = 'MyService1';  // change this to the service name you want
let metricName = 'failure';  // change this to the metric you want

let specificMetric = dependencyMetrics[serviceName][metricName];
```

Comment: The thing is it is to be expanded to MyService2 and any ways I cannot access MyService1 directly from dependencyMetrics

like this :

dependencyMetrics.MyService.failure



can you show me how to access the dictionary keys ?

Comment: When I try some thing like this :

console.log(<MetricInfo>dependencyStackOverflow['MyService']['failure']);

it does not give me any thing concrete just Object Is it even possible doing this like this ?

Comment: Seems like the way to access this is terrible : something like the following  
`console.log(
      Object.keys(dependencyStackOverflow).forEach((key) => {
        const value = dependencyStackOverflow[key];
        Object.keys(value).forEach((key) => {
          console.log(value[key]);
        });
      }),
  );`

Comment: how do you think I should be flattening the hierarchy if needed, f.ex I want a list of all the metrics of all the services regardless as a list, So basically want to flatten the hierarchy 
How exactly do I do that ?
anyways the key thing works and it identifies the correct MetricInfo object properties as I needed it to be  Thanks for that .